# handle three struts html:form with different actions and different submit buttons?

Tags: jquery, html, jsp

I am trying to develop a jsp page which contain 3 forms with three actions. (one action per per each html:form) when submit the first button, all the thing are okay. after pushing the second button, its action fires but no result is shows on the page and everything fade on thee mentioned page. here is the jsp page:

```
<body>
         <html:form styleId="formID"  method="post"  action="/foo.do?method=foo">

          <button id="Search" type="submit" value="search"> Search </button>
          </html:form>

          <html:form styleId="TBLsabkaform" action="/foo1.do?method=foo1">

                 <button id="FirstValidation" type="submit"> test </button>
                 </html:form>

                 <html:form styleId="Finalsubmitform" action="/foo2.do?method=foo2">

                 <button id="FinalValidation" type="submit" > Ok </button>
                 </html:form>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what I understand you can attach the action to the button.

I have no JSP experience, but from my use of HTML this is my suggestion.

```
<button type="submit" formaction="demo_admin.asp">Submit as admin</button>
```

so your code would look like this:

```
<body>
   <html:form styleId="formID"  method="post">
       <button id="Search" type="submit" value="search" formaction="/foo.do?method=foo">Search</button>
   </html:form>

   <html:form styleId="TBLsabkaform"  method="post">
       <button id="FirstValidation" type="submit" formaction="/foo1.do?method=foo1">test</button>
       <button id="FinalValidation" type="submit" formaction="/foo2.do?method=foo2">Ok</button>
   </html:form>
</body>
```

you also do not need multiple forms... 1 form can submit to multiple sources.
If you make use of some isset() checks on the other side then it's basically flawless, in my experience.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
almost forgot a reference :P
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_formaction.asp

By the way - If you wanted to have a unique submision instead of using

```
<button id="FinalValidation" type="submit" formaction="/foo2.do?method=foo2">Ok</button>
```

you could just make the submit button a field by assigning a name and a value that will be unique to the button clicked :)

```
<button id="FinalValidation" type="submit" formaction="/foo2.do" name="method" value="foo2">Ok</button>
```